# Recursively Enumerable Ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Is there an explicit enumeration of the Church-Kleene ordinal $\omega_1^{CK}$?  A general explanation of what it means for an ordinal to be computable and/or recursively enumerable could be helpful too.

Comment: You might find [this description](https://risingentropy.com/constructing-the-church-kleene-ordinal/) of the Church-Kleene ordinal helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $\omega_1^{CK}$ is not remotely close to computable. It turns out that it isn't even [hyperarithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory).

Precisely, we say that a linear order $\alpha$ **has a computable copy** if there is a computable binary relation $\triangleleft$ on $\omega$ such that $(\omega,\triangleleft)$ is a linear order isomorphic to $\alpha$. Note that this $\triangleleft$ will not be unique: a given linear order may have many different "computable copies." Of course "computable" here can be replaced with any other complexity notion - e.g. hyperarithmetic - and similarly we can talk about computable copies of *structures* in general (e.g. groups, rings, fields, ...) by looking at things other than just binary relations. We can also relativize, and talk about structures with copies computable (or hyperarithmetic, or etc.) [relative to a given real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction).

We often abuse terminology and talk about "computable ordinals" (or groups, or rings, or ...) to refer to ordinals which have computable copies.

- Incidentally, it's a good exercise at this point to prove that every linear order which has a c.e. copy has a computable copy, and indeed every c.e. copy of a linear order is literally computable - this isn't true in general structures. *(HINT: it's not even true for partial orders in general ...)*

Surprisingly, for ordinals computability is a very coarse notion: Spector proved that an ordinal $\alpha$ (thought of as a linear ordering) has a hyperarithmetic copy iff it has a computable copy. So $\omega_1^{CK}$ isn't just noncomputable, it's *extremely far* from computable.

A good source for this is Ash/Knight's book [Computable structures and the hyperarithmetic hierarchy](https://www.elsevier.com/books/computable-structures-and-the-hyperarithmetical-hierarchy/ash/978-0-444-50072-4).

---

This is all also tied to another more technical notion of $\omega_1^{CK}$ being "hard to enumerate," namely **admissibility**:

> Suppose $r$ is a real and $\omega_1^{CK}(r)$ is the least ordinal with no $r$-computable copy. Then the level $$L_{\omega_1^{CK}(r)}$$ of [the constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) satisfies [Kripke-Platek set theory (+ infinity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory) - or more snappily, is $\Sigma_1$-admissible.

*EDIT: it's worth noting that there is a converse here, namely that for countable $\alpha$ we have that $\alpha$ is admissible (= $L_\alpha\models$ KP+inf) iff $\alpha=\omega_1^{CK}(r)$ for some $r$. However, note that this does not mean that $r\in L_\alpha$ in such a case (take e.g. $\alpha$ to be an admissible limit of admissibles); we only  have the weaker fact that $L_\alpha[r]$ also satisfies KP+inf.*

In particular, there is no $\Sigma_1$-over-$L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ cofinal function from $\omega$ to $\omega_1^{CK}$. And all the usual ways of climbing up ordinals are much *much* simpler than that. So you really have to break out some big guns to climb up to $\omega_1^{CK}$ from below.

Details of all this can be found in Sacks' book [Higher recursion theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631).